# What does "!" operator mean in javascript when it is used with a non-boolean variable?

Tags: javascript, operators

While reading through javascript codes I've been seeing the `!` operator used for non boolean variables. Here is an example of code not used in.

```
/**
 * loads a resource from a url
 * @param {string} url the url of the resource to load
 * @param {string} relativeTo the url to load relative to
 * @param {function} callback thefunction to call once the file is loaded
 * @private
 */
 GLGE.Wavefront.prototype.loadFile=function(url,relativeTo,callback){
    if(this.relativeTo && !relativeTo) relativeTo=this.relativeTo; //<-- used on a string?
    else this.relativeTo=url;
    if(!callback) callback=this.loaded;    //<-- used on a function?
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(req) {
               // request handling code                
            }
        };
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send("");
    }   
}
```

In this library I've seen many uses of this operator in this manner.

Can someone explain how/if the 'not' function of a string, object or function can be determined when it isn't one half of a Boolean set like the set; `true` and `false`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In JavaScript, the unary negation operator (`!`) will convert its operand into a boolean based on the (somewhat confusing) rules of the language (e.g., ECMA-262 5th Edition).  [This article on JavaScript syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Logical) shows some examples of how the type conversion happens.

Basically, it's an easy way to test for non-"truthiness"; seemingly false values (e.g. `false`, `null`, `0`, `NaN`, the empty string, etc.) will be converted to `false` before being logically negated, and vice versa.  You can test for "truthiness" explicitly by using the Boolean constructor:

```
Boolean(null); // => false
Boolean(NaN); // => false
Boolean(""); // => false
Boolean(0); // => false
Boolean(1); // = >true
Boolean("123"); // => true
Boolean(new Object()); // => true
Boolean(function(){}); // => true
```

Answer (score 20):

Any falsy value will satisfy the `if(!insert_variable_here)` condition, including:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- The empty string `''`
- The number `0`
- `NaN`

If `callback` return evaluates any of those values, the condition will be satisfied.

Even though `null != false`, the following will give you an alert:

```
x = null;
if(!x) {
    alert('"!null" does evaluate to true');
}
```

Regardless of whether or not `null != false` makes sense to you or anyone else, the point is that in JavaScript `null` is a falsy value, and thus a value that would satisfy the condition in my first bit of code listed above.  This, it seems, is **the question you have asked**--not, rather, if `null` should or should not `== false`.

Comment: check my answer, interesting edge case on `null`.

Answer (score 3):

```
!object
```

will return false when the object is undefined, equals to null or 0, true otherwise.

Comment: You forgot some falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

Every variable and object can be equated to `true` or `false`.  In the case of objects, undefined is false, anything else is true.

This actually gives some interesting edge cases http://www.ejball.com/EdAtWork/2005/02/15/JavaScriptWhatIsTrue.aspx

One that kinda blows my mind `null != false` evaluates to `true`

**UPDATE**

Note for all those people bashing me in the comments the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) on page 43 defines the toBoolean conversion of `null` as `false`.  As we're only using a `==` and not doing a type check with `===` I find it very reasonably that I would expect `null == false` to evaluate to `true`.

That specification was published June this year so maybe this is a change, but it appears the specification writers come down on my side of the table in this debate.

Comment: Yes, but `null` is still a falsy value in JavaScript.

Comment: @GarlicFries clearly only in some situations.  `null == false` evaluates to `false` but `!null` does indeed evaluate to true.

Comment: Doesn't blow my mind at all... null does not equal false. This fact has been hammered into my brain since college.

Comment: But that's not what falsy means...

`something_that_is_falsy != false` (except when that 'something' _is_ `false`).  However, `!something_that_is_falsy` will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @Paul we're not doing `===` or `!==` here.  In a comparison of values only, not type, I would expect `null == false` to evaluate to true, otherwise, for consistency, `0 == false` shouldn't evaluate to true.  I know for the most part true and false are really just the values 1 and 0 but `some_falsy_value == false` should really evaluate to true while `some_falsy_value === false` should return false.

Comment: But @Endophage, we're not talking about how it _should_ work, rather about how it _does_ work. ;)

Comment: @GarlicFries I get it, but imo it's bad language design.  One of `value == false` and `value == true` should always return false and one should always return true for the sake of consistency.

Comment: @Endophage, so which of 27==false and 27==true should be true according to you? Wouldn't it blow your mind if 27==true and 42==true yet 27!=42?

Comment: @Paul PHP got it right...  If you're going to provide a `===` operator then when using `==` , `falsy_value == false` should evaluate to true.

Comment: @Henning Makholm not at all.  You supertype (assuming you're not using `===`) until variables can be compared.  Eventually, if the variables share no common parent, they reach Boolean.

Comment: Aren't you confusing Boolean with a top type like Object (in certain other languages)? That must be purely an invention of your own, and you can't expect the world to conform to it. [Everything can be converted to Boolean, yes, but everything can also be converted to a string, so that's not a workable criterion for topness].

Comment: @Henning Makholm Boolean is typically a literal rather than an Object.  You would indeed reach Object which would then be equated to a Boolean.  Apologies for skipping a step there.

Comment: But _why_ do you think the natural thing when comparing two disparate types (and primitive values in ECMAScript are _not_ objects, by the way) would be to convert them to booleans, of all things? That's giving boolean a position of supremacy that nothing supports.

Comment: @Henning Makholm I never said primitives were objects, I thought I was clear on that.  My gripe here is that js doesn't handle falsy values consistently.  See: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: @Endophage I certainly **would** expect 0==false to evaluate to true as 0 represents a value. null represents the absence of a value. null != _ANYTHING_ therefore !null == _SOMETHING_ and (boolean) _SOMETHING_ == true. The reason 0 == false is because false is represented in binary as 0. null is the absence of a 1 or a 0.

Comment: @Paul see my update, also note `null == undefined` evaluates to true.  Also `null + 1 == 1` evaluates to true, one more example of `null` being converted to 0/false

Comment: Actually no that is not an example of null being converted to anything. null == undefined because they are simply 2 human ways of defining nothing. null + 1 **better** equal 1 because what you did was to add _nothing_ to 1. What else would it equal?

Comment: @Paul generally `null + anything` should equal `null` or `NaN`. By your logic, `undefined + 1` should also equal 1, which is doesn't.

Comment: @Endophage: Why do you think JS doesn't actually have `==`? [Here it is](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.1). *"If you use `==` and the types aren't the same, js simply does a `===`..."* No, [here's the algorthim](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) that is used. If the types aren't the same (step 1), there's a lot more work to do (steps 2-10).

Comment: @patrick dw gah, crappy indentation on the ecma-international PDF.  The numbers don't line up and I misread.

Comment: @Endophage: Yeah, the annotated github version is much nicer to read. You can probably see now, but as it does the type coercion, it typically passes back to `==`, which may or may not send it back into steps 2-9, until it eventually has an equal comparison in step 1-3, or it returns `false`.

Comment: @patrick dw still think it's badly designed behaviour...  Especially as the toBoolean of null is defined as false.

Comment: @Endophage In my last comment I misspoke when I equated undefined and null. They are not in fact the exact same thing. undefined is anything that cannot be defined by the javascript interpreter. null is nothing, the absence of a value. Therefore it must also be undefined. I think these concepts are pretty high-level and abstract, so the language writers had to make a hard decision when developing js. In my mind "null is undefined" but "undefined is not necessarily null".

Comment: @Endophage: I'd imagine if they could go back and redo it, they'd do things a little differently. I think I remember someone here (@CMS? @bobince? @T.J Crowder?) commenting that the whole `null == undefined` idea came about because the DOM specification didn't have any concept of `undefined`, but they had `null`, so that's what was/is returned  from its DOM selection methods given 0 matches. So for "simplicity", JS made them available as equal with `==` comparison (or not equal to any other value with `!=` comparison). I don't know if that's true, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: ...now I'm starting to doubt that my recollection of that story is correct. I don't want to put incorrect words in the mouths of those users I mentioned.

Comment: May I suggest taking any further discussion to [chat]?

Comment: @Michael Myers I've posted a Q to get a full answer and help me understand this whole mess better.

Comment: @GarlicFries um... what exactly is "poor form"?  I don't debate how the language IS implemented, the question I posted is trying to understand the rationale behind that choice.

Comment: @GarlicFries now you're just being insulting.  The behaviour is inconsistent, people on my Q agree with that so I'm trying to get some explanation as to why the particular implementation was chosen.  I genuinely have no idea what you think is "poor form".

Comment: @GarlicFries I've set up a chat room if you want to discuss.

Answer (score -3):

It means NOT or false.

It is simply an alternative to:

```
if (callback != null)
{
     //callback is not null
}

if (callback)
{
    //callback is not null
}
```

OR

```
if (this.relativeTo && relativeTo == false)
{
    //some code
}
```